# MSBuild: Produce message that is visible in VisualStudio's "error list" window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, message

Visual Studio has an "Error list" window:

[image: Visual Studio Error list window]

In a msbuild task (in a .csproj file):

- When I use the `<error text="Foo">` tag, I get an error in the error list (and I can hide it by un-toggling errors in that window)
- When I use the `<warning text="Bar">` tag, I get a warning in the error list (and I can hide it by un-toggling warnings in that window)
- When I use the `<message text="Baz">` tag, **I don't see anything in the error list window**. If I go to the output window, I can see the message there (even if I toggle on or off messages).

**How can I, from a MSBuild script, produce messages that show up in the Visual Studio "Error list" window ?**

Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible - see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212481/how-do-i-get-output-to-show-up-in-the-messages-pane-of-the-error-list-for-visual/

Comment: As Lanorkin mentioned, it doesn't appear to be doable via MSBuild. Here's another SO example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2280044/461382  You might consider changing messages to warnings if you want to make sure they show up in the Error List window without crashing the build.

Comment: @Lanorkin: Thanks. I found these posts but thought they were `C++`-specific, especially since MSBuild **does** have a `<Message/>` tag. Now I think of it, I don't think I **ever** saw a "message" in this list, so maybe the button isn't even associated with anything :) .

Comment: @MichaelW: Thanks, I wanted "messages" so I could easily filter them out when I wanted, and just have the important non-fatal warnings.

Comment: You need to set verbosity under Tools -> Options:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2072929/1034547

Comment: @pospec4444 no, I'm not talking about seing the messages in the `output` window, I want to have them show up in the `error list` window (look at the screenshot in my question).